# Discord.js voteskip system music bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a voteskip system for my music bot and there are 2 problems with it.

Problems

- The same person can vote again
- Even when the amount of required votes are reached the song wont skip
  Here is the code

  ```
  else if (cmd === "skip") {
    let queue = distube.getQueue(message.guild.id);
    let channel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!channel) {
     return message.channel.send( "You need to Join Voice Channel" )
   }
    if (!queue) {
     return message.channel.send( "Nothing Playing" )
   }

   if (queue.songs.length < 1){
     return message.channel.send("There are no more tracks left. Add some")
   }


     channel = message.member.voice.channel
     if (!channel){
       message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to skip this song")
     }
     var required = Math.ceil(message.member.voice.channel.size/2)
     if (voteskips.includes(message.member.id)){
       message.channel.send("You already voted for skipping this song")
     }
     voteskips.push(message.member.id)
     message.channel.send(`**Votes : ${voteskips.length}/${channel.members.size}**  ${required - voteskips.length} more votes needed to skip`)

     if (voteskips.length >= required){

       if (queue.autoplay || queue.songs.length > 1) distube.skip(message)
       else distube.stop(message)
       message.channel.send({embeds:[
         new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setTitle("Skipped current track")
         .setColor("LIGHT_GREY")
       ]})


     }


   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I made a careless mistake. Firstly the required variable is supposed to be

```
     var required = Math.ceil(message.member.voice.channel.members.size/2);
```

The next one is that i am supposed to push the authors id into the array. Not simply message.member.id . Here is the updated code.

```
       else if (cmd === "skip") {
  let queue = distube.getQueue(message.guild.id);
  let channel = message.member.voice.channel;
  let members = Math.ceil(message.member.voice.channel.members.size/2)
  if (!channel) {
    return message.channel.send( "You need to Join Voice Channel" )
  }
  if (!queue) {
    return message.channel.send( "Nothing Playing" )
  }
  
  if (queue.songs.length < 1){
    return message.channel.send("There are no more tracks left. Add some")
  }
  
 
 if (voteskips.find(id=>id == message.author.id)){
   message.channel.send("You have already voted")
 }else {
   voteskips.push(message.author.id)
   message.channel.send(`Votes ${voteskips.length}/${members}. ${members - voteskips.length} more votes to skip.`)
 }
 if (voteskips.length === members){
   if (queue.autoplay || queue.songs.length > 1){
     distube.skip(message)
   }else distube.stop(message)
 }



    
   
}
```